# number of threads in flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

i just learn about flask and requests. i want to get the number of working threads when i post request to the server. and i want to measure the time spent of the working threads. so this is my server and my client code:

`server.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import time 
from flaskthreads import AppContextThread

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

def home():
    timeout = time.time() + 10   # 5 minutes from now

    while True:
        test = 0
        if test ==5 or time.time() > timeout:
            break 

    return 'Hello', 200

def main():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded = True, debug = True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`client.py`

```
import os
import requests
import glob
import time 
import base64


url = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/'


def load_data():

    os.chdir('./500_mb')
    for image in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
        with open(image, 'rb') as imageFile:
            # image_s = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
            image_s = {'file_image':open(image, 'rb')}

    return image_s

def send_data():

    start = time.time()
    r = requests.post(url, files = load_data())
    end = time.time()

    print('client 1: {} ms'.format((end - start)*1000))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_data()
```

how do i know the number of working threads ? i just add `threaded = True` on the server. i've been searching the answer and none of them answer my question. thanks in advance !

Answer (score 12):

First of all, the usual disclaimer: This is pretty much irrelevant because you would be able to specify this when you actually move to a [deployment server](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/).

However, I was curious myself, so I decided to trace this back.

The starting point is in [`app.run()`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/24aab7a08d0b3f40d9fc9e49706854ef8be7a05f/src/flask/cli.py#L829) so let's look at what that does:

```
def run_command(
    info, host, port, reload, debugger, eager_loading, with_threads, cert, extra_files
):

...

from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

    run_simple(
        host,
        port,
        app,
        use_reloader=reload,
        use_debugger=debugger,
        threaded=with_threads,
        ssl_context=cert,
        extra_files=extra_files,
    )
```

So, next port-of-call is [`werkzeug.serving` with `run_simple`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/fab74a12263d1eef64b773d06b214821a7ccf6d2/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L809).

From here, you'll be buffeted about the module:

1. First you'll see that this uses [`make_server`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/fab74a12263d1eef64b773d06b214821a7ccf6d2/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L763)
2. `make_server` launches [`ThreadedWSGIServer`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/fab74a12263d1eef64b773d06b214821a7ccf6d2/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L730)
3. ThreadedWSGIServer takes `socketserver.ThreadingMixIn` as an argument.

Head over to `socketserver`. We can see from [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b74c819fab86bedc9b962ea42cfb9b5893fd2dda/Lib/socketserver.py#L664) the following:

```
class ThreadingMixIn:
    """Mix-in class to handle each request in a new thread."""

    ...

    def process_request(self, request, client_address):
        """Start a new thread to process the request."""
        t = threading.Thread(target = self.process_request_thread,
                             args = (request, client_address))
        t.daemon = self.daemon_threads
        if not t.daemon and self.block_on_close:
            if self._threads is None:
                self._threads = []
            self._threads.append(t)
        t.start()
```

So, the answer is that it launches a new thread on each request. If nothing else, it's an interesting exercise in tracing code paths.

---

Edit in Sept 2021: I originally made the mistake of not getting permalinks from git, so different parts of the answer went out of sync with the code paths I was trying to show. I've since corrected that to try be more stable with permalinks but, with several libraries involved, do note that things *could* change at any time. I think the general principle will hold for a while, though.

Answer (score 2):

Each request automatically starts a new thread by default.  If you're interested in testing this out, you have the option to turn off the multi-threading feature by modifying [the file](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/src/flask/app.py), which is located within your system's Python library directory (on Ubuntu it is *~/.local/lib/python3.XX/site-packages/flask/app.py*)

```
options.setdefault("threaded", True)
```

You'll notice that when it's set to **True**, the thread name increments with each request made. Conversely, when it's set to **False**, the thread name remains constant:

```
@app.route("/thread_name", methods=["GET"])
def thread_name():
    return threading.current_thread().name, 200
```